# WPF usercontrol Twoway binding Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I created a Dependency Property in the usercontrol, but however changes in the usercontrol was NOT notified to the Viewmodel

Usercontrol

```
<UserControl x:Class="DPsample.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtName"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

UserControl.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region SampleProperty 

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SamplePropertyProperty
                                            = DependencyProperty.Register("SampleProperty", 
                                            typeof(string), 
                                            typeof(UserControl1), 
                                            new PropertyMetadata(OnSamplePropertyChanged));


    public string SampleProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SamplePropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SamplePropertyProperty, value); }
    }


    static void OnSamplePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (obj as UserControl1).OnSamplePropertyChanged(e);
    }
    private void OnSamplePropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string SamplePropertyNewValue = (string)e.NewValue;

        txtName.Text = SamplePropertyNewValue;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

MainWindow

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DPsample" x:Class="DPsample.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <local:UserControl1 SampleProperty="{Binding SampleText,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99"/>
    <Button Content="Show" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = this.DataContext as MainViewModel;
        MessageBox.Show(item.SampleText.ToString());
    }
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : NotifyViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.SampleText = "test";           
    }

    private string _sampleText;
    public string SampleText
    {
        get { return _sampleText; }
        set { _sampleText = value; OnPropertyChanged("SampleText"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't coded anything that passes changes of the `TextBox.Text` property to `SampleProperty`. You should also use a binding there, with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`.

Comment: @Clemens do i need to use the viewmodel for the usercontrol?

Comment: Not in this case. However, the UserControl might as well directly bind to your view model's `SampleText` property. Then there would be no need at all for `SampleProperty`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Bind the `TextBox.Text` property in the UserControl to its `SampleProperty` like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SampleProperty,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Now you could simply remove your `OnSamplePropertyChanged` callback.

---

You might also register `SampleProperty` to bind two-way by default like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty
    SamplePropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SampleProperty", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Comment: Can't believe I've read so many tutorials and examples on custom UserControls and DependencyProperties and not one mentions the FrameworkPropertyMetadata that solves passing the value back to the model. Great job man!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way to do this is an ElementName Binding. First assign the `x:Name` attribute to the UserControl (for example `x:Name="MyUC"`), then change the binding to:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUC, Path=SampleProperty}"/>
```